# Custom Post Slug same as Parents Category Slug

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, slug

I have removed `/category/` slug in my URLs with Yoast SEO and i have category with parent and child i.e:

- anime
- chuunibyou
- anime info

in another case, i have a custom post type with slug `anime` (same as parent's category slug) and i have posted a new article in that custom post type which has the same slug with category slug i.e :

- `www.domain.com/anime/chuunibyou` <--- custom post
- `www.domain.com/anime/chuunibyou` <--- category slug

when i access my post on that custom post, it always displays the category archive on that slug ( `/anime/chuunibyou/` ) and not the post.

How can i fix this?same slug, but i want to display the post in **custom post type** (anime) and not in category archive.